# EditText not displaying value on adapter call and EditText loses value when listView is Scrolled.

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, baseadapter, android-viewholder

My 1st problem is that in my Activity I'm passing an Amount in my Adapter to use it to set the Edit Text value inside my adapter but it's not showing.
My 2nd problem is that when I change the value of my Edit Text inside my adapter, the value loses when I scroll the List View.

Here my code in adapter:

```
public class CustomListView_InvoiceList extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private List<InvoiceList> invoiceLists;
private float TotalPaymentAmount;

public CustomListView_InvoiceList(Context mContext, List<InvoiceList> invoiceLists, Float totalPaymentAmount) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.invoiceLists = invoiceLists;
    this.TotalPaymentAmount = totalPaymentAmount;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    CheckBox SelectInvoiceCB, PayFull, PayPartial;
    TextView SalesInvoiceNo, InvoiceDate, InvoiceAmount, AmountDue, DueDate, CreditMemoID, CreditMemoDate, CreditMemoReason;
    LinearLayout LL2, LL3;
    EditText TotalAmount;
    ImageView CaptureForm;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    //View v = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.sales_invoice_custom,null);
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.sales_invoice_custom, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.SelectInvoiceCB = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.selectInvoiceCB);
        holder.SalesInvoiceNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SINo);
        holder.InvoiceDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SIDate);
        holder.InvoiceAmount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SIAmount);
        holder.AmountDue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SIAmountDue);
        holder.DueDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SIdueDate);
        holder.PayFull = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.SIFull);
        holder.PayPartial = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.SIPartial);
        holder.TotalAmount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.SITotalAmount);
        holder.CreditMemoID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.creditMemoID);
        holder.CreditMemoDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.creditMemoDate);
        holder.CreditMemoReason = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.creditMemoReason);
        holder.LL2 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll2);
        holder.LL3 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll3);

        holder.SelectInvoiceCB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                invoiceLists.get(getPosition).setSelectInvoice(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
            }
        });

        holder.PayFull.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                invoiceLists.get(getPosition).setPayFull(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                if (holder.PayFull.isChecked()) {
                    holder.PayPartial.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });

        holder.PayPartial.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                invoiceLists.get(getPosition).setPayPartial(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                if (holder.PayPartial.isChecked()) {
                    holder.PayFull.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });

        view.setTag(holder);
        view.setTag(R.id.SITotalAmount, holder.TotalAmount);
        view.setTag(R.id.selectInvoiceCB, holder.SelectInvoiceCB);
        view.setTag(R.id.SIFull, holder.PayFull);
        view.setTag(R.id.SIPartial, holder.PayPartial);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    InvoicePopulate(view,holder, position);

    return view;
}

public void InvoicePopulate(final View view, final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    final String formattedDate = df1.format(c.getTime());

    try {
        dbHelper.openDataBase();

        // LAYOUT VISIBILITY FOR CREDIT MEMOs
        try {
            if (invoiceLists.get(position).getCredit_Memo_ID().equals(null) || invoiceLists.get(position).getCredit_Memo_ID().isEmpty()
                    || invoiceLists.get(position).getCredit_Memo_ID().length() < 1
                    || invoiceLists.get(position).getCredit_Memo_ID().trim().equals("")){
                holder.CreditMemoID.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.CreditMemoDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.CreditMemoReason.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.LL2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.LL3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.LL2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.LL3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.CreditMemoID.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.CreditMemoDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.CreditMemoReason.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.CreditMemoID.setText(invoiceLists.get(position).getCredit_Memo_ID());
                holder.CreditMemoDate.setText(invoiceLists.get(position).getCredit_Memo_Date().substring(0,10));
                holder.CreditMemoReason.setText(invoiceLists.get(position).getCredit_Memo_Reason());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        holder.SalesInvoiceNo.setText(invoiceLists.get(position).getSales_Invoice_ID());
        holder.InvoiceDate.setText(invoiceLists.get(position).getInvoice_Date());
        holder.DueDate.setText(invoiceLists.get(position).getDue_Date());

        float invAmount = 0;
        invAmount = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(invoiceLists.get(position).getInvoice_Amount())*100.00)/(float)100.00;
        holder.InvoiceAmount.setText(String.format("%,.2f",invAmount));
        holder.AmountDue.setText(String.format("%,.2f",invAmount));
        //holder.InvoiceAmount.setText(invoiceLists.get(position).getInvoice_Amount());

        holder.TotalAmount.setTag(position);
        holder.SelectInvoiceCB.setTag(position); // This line is important.
        holder.PayFull.setTag(position); // This line is important.
        holder.PayPartial.setTag(position); // This line is important.


        holder.TotalAmount.setText(invoiceLists.get(position).getAmount_Paid());
        holder.SelectInvoiceCB.setChecked(invoiceLists.get(position).isSelectInvoice());
        holder.PayFull.setChecked(invoiceLists.get(position).isPayFull());
        holder.PayPartial.setChecked(invoiceLists.get(position).isPayPartial());

        try {
            if (invoiceLists.get(position).getAmount_Paid().toString().equals("") ||
                    invoiceLists.get(position).getAmount_Paid().toString().equals("0.0") ||
                    Float.parseFloat(invoiceLists.get(position).getAmount_Paid().toString()) < 1) {
                invAmount = 0;
                invAmountDue = 0;
                invAmountPaid = 0;
                //invAmount = Float.parseFloat(invoiceLists.get(position).getInvoice_Amount());
                invAmount = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(invoiceLists.get(position).getInvoice_Amount())*100.00)/(float)100.00;
                invAmountDue = invAmount - invAmountPaid;
                Log.e("Without AmountPaid ", "Amount Due : " + String.valueOf(invAmountDue));
            } else {
                invAmount = 0;
                invAmountDue = 0;
                invAmountPaid = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(invoiceLists.get(position).getAmount_Paid())*100.00)/(float)100.00;
                //invAmount = Float.parseFloat(invoiceLists.get(position).getInvoice_Amount());
                invAmount = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(invoiceLists.get(position).getInvoice_Amount())*100.00)/(float)100.00;
                invAmountDue = invAmount - invAmountPaid;
                Log.e("With AmountPaid ", "Amount Due : " + String.valueOf(invAmountDue));
            }

            holder.AmountDue.setText(String.format("%,.2f",invAmountDue));
            //holder.InvoiceAmount.setText(invoiceLists.get(position).getInvoice_Amount());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        /*final float finalInvAmount = invAmountDue;
        holder.PayFull.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (holder.PayFull.isChecked()) {
                    holder.PayPartial.setChecked(false);
                    if (holder.SelectInvoiceCB.isChecked()) {
                        invoiceStatusValue = "PAID_FULL";
                        holder.TotalAmount.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(finalInvAmount*100.00)/100.00));
                        //holder.TotalAmount.setText(holder.InvoiceAmount.getText().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        holder.PayPartial.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (holder.PayPartial.isChecked()) {
                    holder.PayFull.setChecked(false);
                    if (holder.SelectInvoiceCB.isChecked()) {
                        invoiceStatusValue = "PAID_PARTIAL";
                        holder.TotalAmount.setText("0.00");
                    }
                }
            }
        });*/

        if (TotalPaymentAmount >= Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(invAmountDue))) {
            holder.SelectInvoiceCB.setChecked(true);
            holder.PayFull.setChecked(true);
            holder.PayFull.setClickable(true);
            holder.PayPartial.setClickable(true);

            holder.TotalAmount.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(invAmountDue * 100.00) / 100.00));

            System.out.println("TotalPaymentAmount: " + TotalPaymentAmount);
            System.out.println("invAmountDue: " + invAmountDue);

            if (Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(invAmountDue)) < 1) {
                Log.e("Computations : ", TotalPaymentAmount + " + " + String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(invAmountDue))));
                Log.e("Equals ", "TotalPaymentAmount = " + TotalPaymentAmount);
            } else {
                TotalPaymentAmount = TotalPaymentAmount - Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(invAmountDue));
            }
        } else {
            if (TotalPaymentAmount < 1) {
                holder.TotalAmount.setText("0.00");
                /*holder.PayFull.setClickable(false);
                holder.PayPartial.setClickable(false);*/

            } else {
                holder.SelectInvoiceCB.setChecked(true);
                holder.PayPartial.setChecked(true);
                holder.PayFull.setClickable(true);
                holder.PayPartial.setClickable(true);
                holder.TotalAmount.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(TotalPaymentAmount * 100.00) / 100.00));

                if ((TotalPaymentAmount - Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(invAmountDue))) < 0) {
                    TotalPaymentAmount = (float) 0.0;
                } else {
                    TotalPaymentAmount = TotalPaymentAmount - Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(invAmountDue));
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        System.out.println("Custom Invoice List: " + e);
    } finally {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend using RecyclerView instead of ListView, a simple implementation will avoid the problem of scrolling.
I recommend these links: 

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Second, the method invoicePopulate * opens the SQLite database every time a view is created, this gives a serious performance problem because with the scroll the views are recreated and you generate multiple instances in the end you will end up with an error and you will not be able to access to the database. For this I recommend that you calculate the data previously and pass it to the adapter already ready.

It is best to use the adapters to only show information, if you need to calculate try to do it before.